# Cloudinary image goes 401 unauthorized on firefox when using modifiers in url

Tags: image, http, firefox, cloudinary, unauthorized

I have this image uploaded on cloudinary:

http://res.cloudinary.com/sylvain-bigonneau/image/upload/v1441562225/fvlmjerhn7vcli4hkbvx.jpg

It loads fine on every browser. But if I want to use modifiers in the url, such as:

http://res.cloudinary.com/sylvain-bigonneau/image/upload/c_fit,f_auto,h_590,w_768/v1441562225/fvlmjerhn7vcli4hkbvx.jpg

It loads fine on Chrome, but I get a 401 Unauthorized error when opening it on Firefox.

Is there some way I can fix this?

I am using Firefox 40.0.3 on Linux Mint 17.

Comment: Your account is disabled because you didn't verify your email. Please log in to your account and validate your email address. BTW. you can see details about the error by looking at the X-Cld-Error response header.

Comment: Thank you for this. Somehow their verification emails won't reach my mailbox. I contacted support, will keep it updated.

Comment: Update: yep, it works! Thanks for that